# Internet Explorer doesn't render button hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to change the style of a button by using this css

```
input[type=submit] {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #94B5CF;
border: 1px solid #739BBF;
float: right;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
background: #A4C1D8;
border: 1px solid #7FA5C6;
}
```

It works fine on all the other browsers except in Internet Explorer 8. I mean it works but not properly, like if i hover the button it will change the color but only for a fraction of a second then reverts to its normal state.

another strange thing is that if i don't float the button to the right side it works fine in IE8.

Comment: Seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Vw5Kb/1/ There's something else causing the problem. Can you include more information about the rest of the code?

Comment: Is the button inside a login form `      <form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="upwd"><br /><br />
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
   </form>`

Comment: Still fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Vw5Kb/2/ Why don't you add more of your stuff to the fiddle until you replicate the behavior you're seeing? (Click update to get a url you can share back with us.) I suspect something else on your page is interfering. Not this stuff at all.

Comment: Just discovered that it works but only if i hover over the border.

Comment: Wow. That's... strange. Maybe @wayne is right, this could be some new bug o.O

Comment: FOUND THE PROBLEM it was this line `<a href="index.php">Home</a>` inside the login form. After i removed it everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `input[type="submit"]` (in quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Are you in Quirks Mode? Add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the html to get it into standards mode.

**Update:**

If its in standards mode it is suppose to work!

csshover.htc would fix it though.

use a php wrapper if your host does not have a mimi type for htc files.

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/x-component' );
include( 'csshover.htc ' );
?>
```

then use

```
myElement, .myClass, #myID {
    [ ...css3 rules... ]
    behavior: url(myphp-csshover.php);
}
```

instead of

```
myElement, .myClass, #myID {
    [ ...css3 rules... ]
    behavior: url(csshover.htc);
}
```

Comment: Well IE8 is supose to support hover on all elements. Maybe you discovered a bug. But csshover.htc would work on IE8. https://code.google.com/p/okprakan/downloads/detail?name=csshover3.htc